# How to drop column index using python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to remove the column index appearing in my combobox as values.
Here's how my combobox looks like now:

(All the numbers shown inside are column index)

as you can see from the combobox image, it is very messy.

[combobox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dODKG.png)

output should be this:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVeBR.png)

data sample:

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WWD2.png)

```
df = pd.read_excel ('N:/TEST/TEST UTILIZATION/IA 2020/Dev/SCS-FT-IE-Report.xlsm', sheet_name= 'FT')
df.sort_values("Customer Name", inplace = True) 
df.drop_duplicates(subset ="Customer Name", inplace = True)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ["Customer Name"])
df3.style.hide_index()

comboExample = ttk.Combobox(window, width=40, values=df3, state="readonly")
comboExample.current(0)
comboExample.grid(column=2, row=2)
```

I tried using `df.reset_index` and `df.style.hide_index` and it doesn't work. Any idea on how to solve this?

Thank you all for your help! :-)

Comment: Can you add a data sample rather than images?

Comment: Have you tried `df.reset_index(inplace=True)`

Comment: You should also include how you assign the values to the combobox.

Comment: Hi Aditya, I have added the data sample. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi  Narendra Prasath, I have tried that and it doesn't work :-(

Comment: Try `df3 = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ["Customer Name"]).reset_index()`

Comment: Hi Henry Yik, updated on the combobox part. I'm not sure if I have assigned it correctly

Comment: IIUC, try `values=df3.columns.tolist()` instead.

Comment: Hi David Erickson, just tried it out and I received an error. KeyError: 58

Comment: Hi Henry Yik, added values=df3.columns but nothing has changed. No errors.